# How to vertically align react font awesome icons

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I am using [react font awesome package](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/icons?name=fa) and it is so annoying to see that some icons do not align vertically properly and tend to be lifted up higher than

[image]

As you can above, i scaled the react font awesome icon to `60px` and it looks awful

here is how i use it within JSX

```
<p>Powered by <FaCcStripe size='60px' /></p>
```

How do i align it vertically to center with the other content or text?
I mostly add the icons along with text and will like the icons to be vertically centered

Comment: Can you send codesandbox link?

Comment: Maybe `align-items: center` with `flex` can help. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div className='container'>
  <p>Powered by</p>
  <FaCcStripe size='60px' />
</div>
```

Comment: how do i align the div to the center of page? now it is far left. also how do i put spacing between the text and the icon? thanks!

Comment: parent div aligns content to center but did not respect the parent div. so will need to align center and also space between text and icon

Comment: Try this : 

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

Comment: perfect, mind updating the answer with that? will accept..thanks a lot